# Запрос выводящий максимальное количество совпадений в одной колонке

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Делаю тут сайт и столкнулся с проблемой, есть база в который 35 тысяч строк,в колонке guid, это id, но не основной, хранятся цифры, нужно найти совпадения, и вывести ту цифру, которая чаще всего используется в этой колонке. За оптимизацию можно не париться, это будет делаться раз в два дня.

Comment: А конечная задача какова? Для чего это может быть нужно?

Comment: Там цифры или числа? То есть нужно вывести, что девятка повторяется чаще всего? Или что в колонке есть одинаковые значения, которые нужно посчитать?

Comment: Числа
Допустим:
аккаунт 2 guid 300
аккаунт 3 guid 300
аккаунт 4 guid 500
аккаунт 5 guid 500
аккаунт 6 guid 500
аккаунт 7 guid 500
Надо получить в итоге тот guid, который 500

Comment: `group by`, `count()` `order by`  `limit` это ключевые слова, которые помогут вам в решении вашей проблемы.

Comment: teran, энти слова я уже видел, я не могу сформировать запрос

Comment: `select guid from table1 group by guid order by count(guid) desc limit 1` как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно вывести, какое значение в колонке GUID повторяется чаще всего, можете воспользоваться этим запросом:

```
SELECT guid, count(*) as count from table GROUP BY guid ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

В итоге вы получите строку с двумя значениями: сам guid и как часто он появляется в таблице.

---

#### UPDATE

Вы можете увеличить лимит, чтобы выбрать не одно самое частое повторение, а несколько. Но будьте аккуратнее, лучше лимит совсем не снимать (особенно если большая таблица)

```
SELECT guid, count(*) as count from table GROUP BY guid ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

А еще можно сделать вот так:

```
SELECT guid, count(*) as count from table GROUP BY guid HAVING count > 1 ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Таким образом у вас будет максимум 5 строк за выботку, где GUID встречается на странице больше одного раза.